# How to Updating JSONField in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-jsonfield

**I'll give coffee to the person who found the solution Help me please.  Query object:The result I want is just to update the value of auth_token**

> My model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
      age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
      configuration=models.JSONField(null=True)


      def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

> Query object:The result I want is just to update the value of auth_token

```
class Bank:
      
    
    def example(self):
       query = Student.objects.get(id=1)
       el =query.configuration
       encoded_hand = json.dumps(el)
       jsonObject = json.loads(encoded_hand) 
       for value in jsonObject:
            checkValue=value['name']
            if checkValue == 'Auth_token':
                backUrl= value['value']
                backUrl = "token"       
                query.configuration = backUrl  # This is not working properly. Bad idea
                query.save()
                print("Ene bol:{}".format(backUrl))
```

> ```
> MyJson :
> ```

```
[
  {
    "name": "Auth_token",
    "value": "sfsdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "Refresh_token",
    "value": "sdfsdfs"   # How to update this value token ? 
  },
  {
    "name": "BaseUrl",
    "value": "test"
  }
]
```